# При переходе на сайт по доменному имени возникает ошибка "Invalid Host header"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, golang, typescript

При переходе на сайт по доменному имени возникает ошибка "Invalid Host header", а если переходить
по ip то работает.

Сервер: Ubuntu 22.4

Серверное ПО: golang + gin

Фреймворк : React

Webpack не использую

Package.json :

```
    {
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs": "^3.3.6",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.107",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.58",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "axios": "^1.0.0",
    "jose": "^4.11.1",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-jwt": "^1.1.7",
    "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.4.0",
    "react-token-auth": "^2.3.8",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=80 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"}
}
```

В чем может быть причина, ответы которые нашел они для webpack

---

Нашел решение проблемы нужно убрать `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`, но оно гробит другое я не могу прослушивать сервер что можно сделать в этом случае?
PS:у серверного по нет выхода в сеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Invalid Host header" ошибка обычно возникает из-за несоответствия имени хоста в URL, который вы пытаетесь посетить, и имени хоста, настроенного на веб-сервере. Когда вы включаете настройку "proxy" в файле package.json, это говорит веб-серверу webpack проксировать некоторые запросы на другой сервер (в данном случае "http://localhost:8080").

Можно отключить проверку, а можно добавить следующий код в файл package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"
}
```